# How to use an altered value of a matched expression as replace value in PhpStorm?

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I have some CSV data where I want to de-double quote some numbers.

example data

```
("string", "34", "some other string"),
("foo", 27, "even more strings!"),
("bar", "11", "one more for luck..")
```

For which I made this expression:

```
"[0-9]"
```

which shows 67 matches. However, I can't figure out how to replace the match with the value without quotes.

I thought of trying `\$i` but that replaces the "numbers" with a literal $i value.

The [PhpStorm regex ref. guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html) and [find and search reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#) doesn't seem to give much info for non-string related regex replacements so how do I de-double quote values that match a certain pattern (`"[0-9]"`) using `CTRL` + `R` in PhpStorm?

Comment: You could use `"([^"]+)"` and replace with `$1`

Comment: @Thefourthbird would that remove all quotes? I'm only going for quotes around numeric values

Comment: If you only want to match digits, you could use  `"([0-9]+)"` to capture 1+ digits and replace with `$1`. Note that it does not take any structure of the data into account like csv or the parenthesis at the start or end.

Comment: @Thefourthbird ah makes more sense, I really need to learn more regex :p ty^^ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for: `"(\d+)"`
Replace by: `$1`

[image]

[Use regex capturing groups and backreferences](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference)